# how could I view google maps search history? (not location history)

Tags: google-maps

how could I view google maps search history?

I mean beyond . a day or two, so eg a month back or a year back.

I don't mean location history.

Answer (score 1):

You can view and search your history on https://myactivity.google.com .
There is the option to „filter by date & product“, from where you can select Maps and a period of time.